# NHibernate IUserType and custom functions for HQL and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In short I wanted to create a custom `IUserType` to represent `IPAddress` from .NET (as an `inet` type in `postgresql`) and to be able to query it with custom functions via `HQL` and `Linq`. I have trouble with implementing a custom function for `Linq`.

What I have thus far:

**A)** I am able to map it:

```
public class SomeEntityMapper : ClassMap<SomeEntity> {
   public SomeEntityMapper() {
       ...
       Map(x => x.IpAddressField)
                 .CustomSqlType("inet")
                 .CustomType<IPAddressUserType>()
       ...
   }
}
```

IUserType implementation below:

```
[Serializable]
public class IPAddressUserType : IUserType
{
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Equals(y); 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return 0;

        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        if (names.Length == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected at least 1 column");

        if (rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal(names[0])))
            return null;

        object value = rs[names[0]]; 

        return value;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(DbCommand cmd, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        NpgsqlParameter parameter = (NpgsqlParameter) cmd.Parameters[index];
        parameter.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Inet;

        if (value == null)
        {
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        { 
            parameter.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        IPAddress copy = IPAddress.Parse(value.ToString());
        return copy;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        if (cached == null)
            return null;

        if (IPAddress.TryParse((string)cached, out var address))
        {
            return address;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return value.ToString();

    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes => new SqlType[] { new NpgsqlSqlType(DbType.String, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Inet),  };

    public Type ReturnedType => typeof(IPAddress);

    public bool IsMutable => false;
}

public class NpgsqlSqlType : SqlType
{
    public NpgsqlDbType NpgDbType { get; }

    public NpgsqlSqlType(DbType dbType, NpgsqlDbType npgDbType)
        : base(dbType)
    {
        NpgDbType = npgDbType;
    }

    public NpgsqlSqlType(DbType dbType, NpgsqlDbType npgDbType, int length)
        : base(dbType, length)
    {
        NpgDbType = npgDbType;
    }

    public NpgsqlSqlType(DbType dbType, NpgsqlDbType npgDbType, byte precision, byte scale)
        : base(dbType, precision, scale)
    {
        NpgDbType = npgDbType;
    }
}
```

}

**B)** I am able to query it using HQL and a custom function (`inet_equals`) I implemented.

```
using(var session = _factory.OpenSession()) {
   var q = session.CreateQuery("from SomeEntity as s WHERE inet_equals(s.IpAddressField, :ip)"); 
       q.SetParameter("ip", IPAddress.Parse("4.3.2.1"), NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(IPAddressUserType)));
}
```

Custom Postgresql Dialect extending the HQL functions implementation below:

```
 public class CustomPostgresqlDialect : PostgreSQL83Dialect
    {
        public CustomPostgresqlDialect()
        {
            RegisterFunction("inet_equals", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Boolean, "(?1::inet = ?2::inet)"));
        }
    }
```

**C)** I want to be able to query it using LINQ like so:

```
using(var session = _factory.OpenSession()) {
   var q = session.Query<SomeEntity>()
           .Where(s => s.IpAddressField.InetEquals(IPAddress.Parse("4.3.2.1")));
   }
```

Custom LINQ Generator for NHibernate provider below:

```
 public static class InetExtensions
    {
        public static bool InetEquals(this IPAddress value, IPAddress other)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }  
    }

    public class InetGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        public InetGenerator()
        {
            SupportedMethods = new[]
            {
                ReflectHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => InetExtensions.InetEquals(default(IPAddress), default(IPAddress))) 
            };
        } 
        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
            HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            HqlExpression lhs = visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression();
            HqlExpression rhs = visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression(); 

            return treeBuilder.BooleanMethodCall(
                "inet_equals",
                new[]
                {
                    lhs,
                    rhs 
                }
            );
        }
    }

    public class ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry :
        DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
            : base()
        {
            this.Merge(new InetGenerator());
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately when using `LINQ` I get this exception:

`HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: System.Net.IPAddress`

Interestingly, this is the exact same error I get if I omit the `NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(IPAddressUserType))` parameter inside the `HQL` query.

Which leads me to believe I am on the right track, but I can't figure out what I may be missing exactly. I assume I need to inform NHibernate inside the Generator that this is a custom `UserType` (just like I did with the `HQL` query via the `NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(IPAddressUserType))` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

To hint NHibernate to use the proper UserType use: `MappedAs` extension method, like so:

```
using(var session = _factory.OpenSession()) {
   var q = session.Query<SomeEntity>()
           .Where(s => s.IpAddressField.InetEquals(
                 IPAddress.Parse("4.3.2.1").MappedAs(NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(IPAddressUserType))
            );
```

}

Comment: Thank you @krdx. I posted a new answer for anyone who is still stuck in **NHibernate 3.3.2.GA** and doesn't have the `MappedAs` extension method yet.

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2019 and I'm still stuck on version **3.3.2.GA of NHibernate** and the `MappedAs` extension method exists only on version **4.x** onwards.

My scenario was the need to pass a large string as a parameter to a supported method in an `HqlGeneratorForMethod`.

I created the following class to store any large string to use as a parameter of any method throughout the application:

```cs
public class StringClob
{
    public StringClob()
    {
    }

    public StringClob(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public virtual string Value { get; protected set; }
}
```

In order to link the `NHibernateUtil.StringClob` type with the `string` value I had the idea to create a mapping for my class without informing table mapping just the property (**I use FluentNHibernate to map class**):

```cs
public class StringClobMap : ClassMap<StringClob>
{
    public StringClobMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Value, "VALUE").CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("VARCHAR(MAX)").Length(int.MaxValue / 2);
    }
}
```

And now hypothetically following the example of @krdx the usage would look like this:

```cs
using(var session = _factory.OpenSession()) 
{
    var q = session.Query<SomeEntity>()
                   .Where(s => s.IpAddressField.InetEquals(new StringClob("<large_string_here>")));

    // ...
}
```

Therefore by passing the `StringClob` class as a parameter, NHibernate gets the custom type defined in the mapping.

I hope I helped those who still use **NHibernate 3.3.2.GA**.